# Combining results from different aggregate queries

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-aggregation

If you have 3 different MongoDb Aggregate queries based on 3 different collections, each calculating a score for that Dept in a company, how does one `combine / $project` the results into 1 combined executive report by use of query, without storing the individual aggregation results.

In essence, can I run parallel aggregation pipeline queries on different collections and combine the results in a final pipeline without storing intermediate results?